# How to validate an excel file uploaded using FileUpload Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, validation, file-upload

I have a requirement to browse an excel file from the local system, perform some validations on it and then if the validations return true, insert the excel into a database.

I have worked previously on `FileUpload` Control and know how to browse a file and save it somewhere.

What I am not getting is how will I read the excel row by row and perform validations on it.

I searched for `FileUpload1.FileContent.Read()` method, but don't know will it be able to read the excel row by row and stuffs.

Ex of a kind of validation: Read 2 columns in a row and add those 2 values in a third column, if this added value is greater than a default value, return me a false and likewise.

Experts please give some pointers.

Anurag

Comment: Also look into the Open XML SDK, supposedly it can read excel files.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Comment: Hi Ryios: Thanks for the suggestions..will look into them.

Comment: I deleted the other two upon realizing your more interested in the contents of the excel data than validating that is an actual excel file.  I think the Open XML SDK will do everything you need, just a matter of learning it.

Comment: Yep.. your right Ryios..Validating that its an actual excel file will be easy as far as I think..more interested in performing some checks in the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do validations and stuffs on my excel by using a 3rd party library, namely `ExcelLibrary`.

It can be found out at https://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/

It helped me to read my excel as a `DataSet` and perform whatever validations I needed.

Regards

Anurag

Answer (score 1):

```
You can do this using jquery....

$('#filediag').change(function () {
                readSingleFile();
                //return true;
            });

function readSingleFile() {
                var uploadDialogValue = document.getElementById("filediag").value;
                if (uploadDialogValue != "") {
                    var extension = uploadDialogValue.substring(uploadDialogValue.length - 3, uploadDialogValue.length);
                    if (extension == "xls") {
                        //alert(extension);
                        document.getElementById('<%=btnOK.ClientID%>').click();

                    }
                    else
                        alert("Please select .xls format file");
                }
                return false;
            }
```